# Symfony form listener

Tags: php, symfony

I have form with choice field `customer` type `entity` and I want when select some customer in another place(input or label, whatever) change data, I use example from cook book but not work

my form

```
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('customer', 'entity', array(
            'class' => Customer::class,
            'property' => 'name',
            'empty_value' => 'Choice Customer',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) {
                /** @var CustomerRepository  $repository */
                return $repository->getAllQuery();
            },
            'required' => true
        ));

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            /** @var Customer $customer */
            $customer = $data->getCustomer(); //always have null, why ?
            $positions = null === $customer ? '-' : 'its_work';

            $form
                ->add('invoicing_address', 'text', [
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => $positions
                ]);
        }
    );


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'out_bound_invoice';
    }
```

my js ?

```
var $sport = $('#out_bound_invoice_customer');
// When sport gets selected ...
$sport.change(function() {
// ... retrieve the corresponding form.
var $form = $(this).closest('form');
// Simulate form data, but only include the selected sport value.
var data = {};
data[$sport.attr('name')] = $sport.val();
// Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
$.ajax({
    url : $form.attr('action'),
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    data : data,
    success: function(html) { // in html always have empty, like ''
        // Replace current position field ...
        $('#out_bound_invoice_address').replaceWith(
            // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
            $(html).find('#out_bound_invoice_address')
        );
        // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
    }
});
});
```

when I change customer in js in data have name form and customer name key and data id and then in action in request I see this data

[image]
[image]

when using event form `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` in `$customer` I have customer entity

```
        $builder->get('customer')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $customer = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $customer);
        }
    );
```

and I want understand why needed `PRE_SET_DATA, POST_SET_DATA` for this event I have `null`

my twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_label(form.customer, 'customer')}}
    {{ form_widget(form.customer, {'attr': {'class': 'select2'}}) }}

    {{ form_label(form.invoicing_address)}}
    {{ form_widget(form.invoicing_address) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

why all time I have null in `$customer` in form listener and how change another field (label or default data, whatever in another field)?

Comment: The FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA event is dispatched at the beginning of the Form::setData(). So you cannot have some data at this moment. What about POST_SET_DATA?

Comment: $event->getData() delivers the Customer entity already, I think you shouldn't call getCustomer() any more. Or you have the method $customer->getCustomer()??

Comment: `POST_SET_DATA` have null in customer too

Comment: this for for `invoice` entity `$data = {AppBundle\Entity\OutboundInvoice}` this entity in variable `data` and have function `getCustomer`

Comment: but you inject a Customer class: 'class' => Customer::class,

Comment: yes, in form for `OutboundInvoice` I inject customer choice field and when change this input, select some customer, in form event in `$data = $event->getData()` have entity `OutboundInvoice`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135699/discussion-between-shuba-ivan-and-rawburner).